# Trigonometry-Complex Numbers Based Problem

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $2^7\cos^5x * \sin^3x$=$a\sin8x- b\sin 6x +c\sin 4x + d\sin 2x$ where $x$ is real then what will be the value of $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4$?

Even a hint will suffice... I don't know how to proceed! I initially tried using complex numbers... but I'm stuck

Comment: "Using complex numbers" is not a good description of what you have tried.

Comment: i took  z= cos x + i sin x...and 1/z =cos x - i sin x so 2 cos x=(z+1/z) and 2 i sin x =z- 1/z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you have commented, setting $z=\cos x+i\sin x$

$$(2\cos x)^5(2i\sin x)^3=\left(z+\frac1z\right)^5\left(z-\frac1z\right)^3$$

$$\iff2^7\cos^5x\sin^3x\cdot i^3=\left(z+\frac1z\right)^2\left(z^2-\frac1{z^2}\right)^3$$

Expand the right hand side and use $z^n-\dfrac1{z^n}=2i\sin(nx)$

Answer (score 1):

assuming  $$ 2^7\cos^5x * 3\sin^5x = a\sin8x- b\sin 6x +c\sin 4x + d\sin 2x, $$  is an identity, it is equivalent to $$12 \sin ^5 u =  a\sin4u- b\sin 3u +c\sin 2u + d\sin u.$$
taking $u = \pi/4, \pi/2, 3\pi/4$ in order, we get 
$$ 3/\sqrt 2 = -b/\sqrt 2 +c + d/\sqrt 2, \, 12 = d, \, 3/\sqrt 2 = -b/\sqrt 2 - c +d/\sqrt 2$$  from these we get $$c = 0, d = 12, b = 9.$$ put $u = \pi/6,$  we get $$ \frac 3 8 =a\sqrt 3/2 -b +c\sqrt 3/2 + d /2\to a = \frac{9\sqrt 3} 4$$

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using the double angle formulas several times on the right hand side?

Comment: Hmm..i dont think it would be a good technique..it will only increase the size of solution greatly..i feel there's a better approach